# Cordova App act like a browser with custom Javascript

Tags: cordova, apache-cordova

When Cordova initialize, i want to redirect to some page with `window.location.href = url` but i still want to execute some javascript on the page after the redirect.

I want to do something like a userscript in a Cordova app, the reason is because Cordova don't receive or send cookies from ajax requests with cross domain.

Is that possible? I think the key is inject the javascript inside the Cordova's webview but i have no ideia how to do it and not even know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved installing the `cordova-plugin-cookiemaster`. Now i can access the cookies from other domains.